# Electron converted to uwp--problems when submitted to the windows store

Tags: javascript, uwp, electron

Here is what microsoft told me.Is it possible to browse the web without using the framework provided by microsoft??

### Please take the following action

We reviewed your submission and identified some changes that are needed before we can publish or update the app. Please make these changes and resubmit your app. For more information, contact reportapp@microsoft.com Please include your app ID so we can act quickly.

**Capabilities** : 10 Centennial Active Presence Check

### Notes To Developer

Your app has not been approved for the Centennial program.

**Tested Devices**: (Win 10 S) Microsoft Surface Laptop, Acer Iconia W700

**Capabilities**: 10 Centennial Win32 Presence Check

### Notes To Developer

Your account has not been approved for the Centennial program.

**Tested Devices**: (Win 10 S) Microsoft Surface Laptop, Acer Iconia W700

**App Policies**: 10.2.1 Browsers

### Notes To Developer

Because your app browses the web, it must use the Windows Platform HTML and JavaScript engines. You can find information about the platform here:
dge Developer Blog: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/08/27/creating-your-own-browser-with-html-and-javascript/
GitHub Browser Project: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JSBrowser/tree/v1.0
XAML WebView API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx
HTML WebView API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx

Tested Devices: (Win 10 S) Microsoft Surface Laptop, Acer Iconia W700

[here is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAPlo.png)

Answer (score 5):

[Store Policy 10.2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/windows/agreements/store-policies#102-security) seems pretty clear on this:

> Products that browse the web must use the appropriate HTML and JavaScript engines provided by the Windows Platform.

So no, you can't browse the web without using Microsoft's own framework for doing this.

I can't say how the store detects submissions using alternative frameworks, but personally I wouldn't spend any time trying to find a way around it.  Even if there was an alternative way (and I'm not saying there is), I would expect Microsoft to wisen up to it in time and kick out of the store any apps using it.